# How to measure the time to load Initial perspective in RCP Application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Whenever I am opening my RCP Application I need to measure the time to Load Initial Perspective. How can I find the places where the Initial Perspective is starts loading and where its loaded completely?

Answer (score 0):

well if you have access to the source code, and you can debug, the `WorkbenchPage#createPerspective` API could be benchmarked.

I'm guessing you want to test the efficieny of your code, and not Eclipse's. Maybe benchmark the part you are creating?

Comment: @venkateshg Maybe try a manual debug with some benchmarking library? You put sysouts at creation and open time with milliseconds information

Comment: Is there any listener for perspective loading ? (like IExecutionListener for ResetPerspective, with this listener I can measure the time to Reset a Perspective by using preExecute() and postExecuteSuccess() Methods).